# Spring Feign client call enters exception block when it should stay in try block

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Need some small help about Spring Feign client. So here is the situation,

I have 2 Spring boot services. Let’s say Service A and Service B. I have configured my Service A with Feign client through which I call the Service B method.

So here is the code for my Service A,

My FeignCleint config interface,

```
@FeignClient(name = "FeignClient", url = "http://localhost:8081/ServiceB/hello")
public interface FeignApi {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> hello();
}
```

And my rest controller that uses above feign config to call the Service B method,

```
@RestController
public class ApiController {

    @Autowired
    private FeignApi feignApi;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callServiceB")
    public ResponseEntity<?> companyInfo() {
        ResponseEntity<?> response = new ResponseEntity("OK Response", HttpStatus.OK);
        try {
            response = feignApi.hello();

            // Code for some other things related to application.

            return response;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Service A Exception block reached.");
            return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

below is my controller for Service B,

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() throws Exception {

        if (true) {
            throw new Exception("Service B Exception...");
        }
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And my Controller advice to handle the exception that I am manually throwing,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception exception, Model model) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Caused due to : " + exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Now my flow is like below,
As you can see, I am calling service B from service A using feign client. My service B is throwing an exception manually which I am catching using the controller advice and sending the exception details as an ResponseEntity back to the calling service A. So that Service A can process the details and move forward based on that.

The problem is when I hit the call from Service A using

> http://localhost:8080/feign/callServiceB

The service B fails as expected. Now what I expect is that the Service A should receive the response back in form of the ResponseEntity. But what really happens is that the flow enters the exception block instead of staying in the try block. I can see this line printed,

```
"Service A Exception block reached."
```

This is what I don't understand. If I have managed the service B exception using controller advice and sent back the response to service A in form of ResponseEntity, then how come the flow of service A enters catch block. I expect it to stay in try block only as I want to process further based on the data.

Any idea, how can I get around this thing? Or is this how it will behave even when I am using controller advice to manage exceptions? What should be the expected behavior in this case?

Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

By default Feign throws FeignException for any error situation. 
Make use of fallback mechanism to handle failures.

```
@FeignClient(name = "FeignClient", url = "http://localhost:8081/ServiceB/hello", fallback= FeignApiFallback.class)
public interface FeignApi {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<?> hello();
}

@Component
class FeignApiFallback implements FeignApi {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> hello() {
        //do more logic here
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

make sure you add below property to wrap methods in hystrix commands in recent releases

```
feign.hystrix.enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I add this new component by providing fallback details, I still don't get the control inside that method? Like I just added a sysout to see if the flow gets there or not, but it just skips it. Ho will the fallback approach help me fetching the error from Service B and make to keep the flow in try block only? I am sorry if this is straight forward, but I am new to this, so please let me know.

Comment: Also, when I try to add "feign.hystrix.enabled=true" in my properties file, it shows me, 'feign.hystrix.enabled' is an unknown property. I dont know why :(

Comment: well if you want to know whats the error in that case you got to do custom handling or make use of custom decoder. I can share you links which will help you. https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/wiki/Custom-error-handling.

Comment: Fallback will get involved if fallback property is defined properly @FeignClient annotation and available as a bean. update the code to figure out why its not called.

Comment: Thanks @Barath. I looked at that link for custom error handling. But that just seems to be small piece of code. Do you happen to know any full example on Github that I can actually download and import in my eclipse to understand better?

Comment: Also, how to solve "'feign.hystrix.enabled' is an unknown property." issue?

Comment: @WebNoob its strange why it is not picked but you can read recent release notes about it. what exactly you are looking for as a sample ? handling error / fallback mechanism ?

Comment: @WebNoob made a sample here : [feign-client-exception](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/stackoverflow-issues/tree/master/issue-52889703-feign-client-exception)

Comment: thanks a lot. I will download your code and give it a try on my local machine. I will let you know what was the issue with my code. Thanks again for creating this example for making me understand. I appreciate it man.

Comment: I went through code, it now goes in the fallback. The only issue I have is, I can't get the custom message that I send through while handling the exception. So Inventory calls product, I throw exception manually with message, "Service B Exception..." then controllerAdvice handles that exception and send back a ResponseEntity with message "Caused due to : Service B Exception...". Now the flow comes in ErrorDecoder where I print the response. But here in the response I don't see the "Caused due to : Service B Exception..." mesage that I had set. Am I doing something wrong? Please see.

Comment: Also, inside the fallback method, how do I get the actual response to play with? There are no parameters to the fallback method. So how do I tackle the exception related handling over there?

Comment: Yes I did. but in that response object, there is nothing specific to exception message. The reason is null, status is 500, response body is a inputstream object. but I am not sure how can I fetch anything out of it. Can you suggest how can I get the original exception details from this Response object?

Comment: @WebNoob I'm working on a similar problem, maybe this link might be helpful 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-fallback

Comment: @WebNoob if you use the above link, implementing only FallbackFactory will provide you the exception cause from one service to another, you don't need to create an error decoder, only problem I'm facing now if I do implement it the way it is shown in link, I will have to unnecessarily implement all the methods of my controller, which I don't want

Answer (score 2):

Any status other than 200, feign client will consider it as an exception and you are setting HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR in your controller advice.

You can use custom ErrorDecoder

refer https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/wiki/Custom-error-handling